# Search for part of string with grep in all files in folder and subfolders

Tags: grep

I have .html files in directories and subdirectories. I need to extract all strings that starts with "domain.com". Part of string can look like this:

["https://example.com/folder1",
href="https://example.com/anotherfolder2" target="
etc.

What I want to extract is:
folder1
anotherfolder2
etc.

from all files in all folders to one list, each word - new line.

Found some examples on StackOverflow with many likes, but not worked. I tried like this (from some examples):

```
grep -Po '(?<=example.com=)[^,]*'
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you. **Show us the actual code that you've tried**, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I edited my post with what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
grep "example.com" your-directory -r | grep -o '".*"' | cut -d \" -f2| sed -e 's/https:\/\/example.com\///g'
```

1. `grep "example.com" your-directory -r | grep -o '".*"' your-directory -r | cut -d \" -f2` extracts the content of quoted string
2. `sed -e 's/https:\/\/example.com\///g'` get the suffix of `https://example.com/`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this shows many other parts of the string which I do not need and with this not showing what I need) Examples of what it shows but I do not need: from this "g376[id="sc-1s4r656-0"]{content:"jQw" it shows "sc-1s4r656-0". Or from this "</p><h3 id="where-can-you-buy">Wh" it shows "where-can-you-buy"

Comment: But from this string "href="https://example.com/folder1" it does not show folder1. And from this string "chat":["https://example.com/folder2","htt" it does not show folder2

Comment: There can be also example2.com links, but I need only cuts from example.com strings.

Comment: I have edited the answer and add `grep "example.com" your-directory -r |` at the beginning, it should exclude strings don't contain example.com

Comment: That also do not find strings I want. I tried to edit myself and what I achieved is this command finds and show exactly URLs that I need and shows them as list but only domains like example.com without /folder1 part. Can you help me modify it so it cuts domain and leaves folder1? Here is the command: `grep -o "example\.com" "your-directory"`

Comment: `grep -oha "example\.com" "your directory" -r` this one shows list of example.com without /folder1 part and I need opposite))

Comment: This one shows only uniq URLs with folder1 part: `grep -oha "example\.com/[^\"]*" "your-directory" -r | sort | uniq ` Which is almost what I want. As an option it would be great to cut beginning "example.com" but this I can do with find & replace in any editor. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "https://example.com/folder1" | tr -s '/' | tr '/' '\n' > file
sed -i '1d' file
sed -n '1p' file # This will give you example.com
sed -n '2p' file # This will give you folder1

sed -i 1s'@example\.com@newsite.com@' file
echo "http://" > nf
sed -n '2,$p' file >> nf
cat nf | tr '\n' '/' > newfile
cat newfile # This should be http://newsite.com/folder1
rm -v ./nf
```